# node.js - pngjs error: "Stream not writable" randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, png

I am working with [pngjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs/) through many of it's methods. Most of the time, they work fine. However, like in the following example, I get an error: "Stream is not writable"

```
var fs = require('fs'),
PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;

var dst = new PNG({width: 100, height: 50});
fs.createReadStream('http://1.1m.yt/hry7Eby.png') //download this picture in order to examine the code.
    .pipe(new PNG())
    .on('parsed', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

This case is not singular, I get this error on 1 random png image once a day, through all of pngjs methods, and that error obviously crashes my app.
(note: you can't use the http link I gave you with a readStream, you will have to download & rename it and do something like):

```
fs.createReadStream('1.png')
```

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the library, though I'm wary of saying so as I'm no expert in PNGs. The parser seems to complete while the stream is still writing. It encounters the IEND, and so calls this:

```
ParserAsync.prototype._finished = function() {
  if (this.errord) {
    return;
  }

  if (!this._inflate) {
    this.emit('error', 'No Inflate block');
  }
  else {
    // no more data to inflate
    this._inflate.end();
  }
  this.destroySoon();
};
```

If you comment out the `this.destroySoon();` it finishes the image correctly, instead of eventually calling this function:

```
ChunkStream.prototype.end = function(data, encoding) {

  if (data) {
    this.write(data, encoding);
  }

  this.writable = false;

  // already destroyed
  if (!this._buffers) {
    return;
  }

  // enqueue or handle end
  if (this._buffers.length === 0) {
    this._end();
  }
  else {
    this._buffers.push(null);
    this._process();
  }
};
```

...which would otherwise end up setting the `stream.writeable` to `false`, or, if you comment that out, to pushing a null value into the `_buffers` array and screwing up the `ChunkStream._processRead`.

I'm fairly certain this is a synchronicity problem between the time the zlib parser takes to complete and the time the stream takes to complete, since if you do this synchronously it works fine:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('pic.png');
var png = PNG.sync.read(data);
var buff = PNG.sync.write(png);
fs.writeFileSync('out2.png', buff);
```